# Do I have to put "the" before both

Tags: definite-article

> These files were used to complete the dose distribution calculation using **both** the DPM and Penelope codes.

Comment: We don't say _the both_, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @KateBunting This comment is addressed to the both of you.

Comment: @CJDennis I was going to put "We never say _the both_" until I remembered the idiom _the both of you_, which is nonstandard in my (British) English but according to [this](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2009/08/bigger-than-the-both-of-us.html) more common in American English. For simplicity, I didn't mention it, but thought it likely that someone else would do so.

Comment: @KateBunting This question needs a good answer (not in a comment) about when, if ever, "the" is used before "both", and possibly which regions as well if it's not standard.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Faten!  Your sentence as written - "These files ... using both .. " is perfectly correct.  It would be incorrect in this sentence to add an article prior to "both".

Answer (score 1):

When speaking of something that applies to two different things, *both A and B* is used without any need for *the*.

The expression *the both of us* (or *you* or *them*) is sometimes used when speaking of or on behalf of two people. This is acceptable in speech but  not in formal written language. It is most common in American and Irish English.

Comment: I think there is some subtle context missing here.

Answer (score 1):

First, a shout-out to the OP for using the Penelope code. If it's the one I think it is, hey, you are in my industry.

You would put the "the" in as though the "both" was not there.

> We traveled to the event using public transportation.
>   We traveled to the event using private transportation.
>   We traveled to the event using both public transportation and private transportation.
>
> We traveled to the event using our car.
>   We traveled to the event using the subway.
>   We traveled to the event using both our car and the subway.
>
> We traveled to the event using the taxi service.
>   We traveled to the event using the subway.
>   We traveled to the event using both the taxi service and the subway.

You could substitute "by subway" for "the subway."

In the OP's question, it depends on whether you would say "the" for each single item. I am expecting you would, if it's the Penelope code I think it is.  Also, it's my "office style" to put the word "code" by each code rather than putting "codes" at the end. So the following.

> These files were used to complete the dose distribution calculation using the DPM code.
>   These files were used to complete the dose distribution calculation using the Penelope code.
>   These files were used to complete the dose distribution calculation using both the DPM code and the Penelope code.